# good way to keep file differenciation in memory

Tags: c#, filepath

I have 12 media files with some short music. These files are some how distinguish, as having all (I mean one file content from beginning to end) same content or different contents.

File names are:

1. a1_same.wav  // from beginning to end it contains the same content
2. a2_diff.wav  // from beginning to end it contains the different content
3. a3_diff.wav
4. a4_diff.wav
5. a5_same.wav
   ...... 
   till 12.

Now I read all these files and iterate through the file name to distinguish
if the contents are same or diff

```
// just a pseudo code - syntax may be wrong
foreach(var file in abcCollection)
{
    if(file.FilePath.Contains("Same"))
    {
        // then same
    }
    else
    {
        // different
    }
}
```

But I am not satisfied with this kind of check with (checking with file name string for same or different).

Is there any other way to do the same? I mean keeping some say primary key in memory or maintaining some in memory dictionary or list etc...honestly I do not have any clue :-(

If you have any idea then please share.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a hashing function such as MD5 to quickly find if the files physical contents are the same.

The hashing function takes a piece of input data (the file contents) and runs it through a repeatable algorithm that will always return the same value given the same input data, but will return a different value if the input data is in any way different.

This technique is commonly used by download sites and content distributors to help the downloader verify that a file has not been corrupted or tampered with, as they can compare the hash value of the received file against the published hash value provided by the file host.

EDIT: Note that this relies on the files being binary equal, it is not an audio comparison and will not work for files which contain the same audio clip but have different amounts of silent lead-in or lead-out at the start and end of the clips, or if they were different bit rates or had different meta data (MP3 tags etc.) in the file.

[MD5 - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5)

Comment: Sorry, I think you misinterpreted my question. The file contents are different or same is already known by its name it self. But where I need help is the code refactoring of the below code:   foreach(var file in abcCollection) { if (file.FilePath.Contains("Same") { // then some logic for same files} else { // logic for different files})